# Can fiddler access local machine data?

Tags: security, http, passwords, fiddler

One of customers have reported that they can see the password being transferred as clear text, they probably tried tool like a fiddler to capture the HTTP request/response. So my question is is it possible using fiddler or any other tool is it possible  for  someone to monitor the http traffic on that local  computer at the moment the user entered the password and clicked to login ?

Comment: While Fiddler decrypts traffic at the network layer, locally running software can, of course, simply read passwords and other data out of your browser's memory.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is accessing the website without using SSL (i.e. by going to "http://" instead of "https://"), then it is possible to see all of the traffic between the website and the browser, and not only on the local computer but also on the network that the computer is connected to.

If the user is accessing the website via HTTPS, Fiddler is able to act as a proxy and decrypt the traffic between the browser and the server by using a special SSL certificate (thanks to @user18044 for clarification in the comments below).

In your case Fiddler is NOT accessing browser memory directly to get to the password in clear text.

Comment: @pbhkrv. thanks yes the HTTPS is enabled. Question si do fiddler or any such tool have direct access to local machine memory ?

Comment: According to the fiddler product page, it's capable of recording HTTPS traffic (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/web-traffic-recording). It's not doing that by accessing memory, but by inserting itself between the browser and the server. If you are interested in the gory details, here is an [interesting thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/httpfiddler/DecryptHTTPS/httpfiddler/xEOcJItep9A/fYVjAK_D6XgJ) on Fiddler's mailing list. It's using a custom SSL certificate that browsers trust, I think.

Comment: @pbkhrv If you enable the https debugging option in Fiddler, it asks your permission to add its certificate to your trusted root store. It then installs itself as a proxy server for all your http(s) traffic.